# Android Eclipse Fatal Error

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-activity

Im trying to make my first app with eclipse and phonegap. But when I try to run the app I got this message:

```
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my.first.app/my.first.app.MyFirstAppActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.first.app.MyFirstAppActivity
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.first.app.MyFirstAppActivity
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
06-26 20:50:03.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     ... 11 more
```

The manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" > 
    <activity android:name=".MyFirstAppActivity" 
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
              android:label="@string/app_name" > 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>      
</application>
```

I have followed exactly the instructions in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides

Here is my MyFirstAppActivity.java file:

```
package my.first.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;


public class MyFirstAppActivity extends DroidGap { // DroidGap
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

And AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".MyFirstAppActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to declare `MyFirstAppActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Make sure your manifest contains something like this in between the `<application>` and `</application>` tags:

```
<activity android:name=".MyFirstAppActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyFirstAppActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: for the love of god, post it as an edit in your original post... i can't read it all bunched up in a comment like that lol

Comment: @KostadinBuglow, I added it for you... in the future you should add code to your original post. You should also make sure your code is readable, indented, and nicely formatted so it doesn't give people a headache when they read it :)

Comment: sorry, im new on the site...sorry again

Comment: don't worry about it, most beginners do it too :). is the manifest in your post exactly the way it looks in the file? can you add the entire file (i.e. everything between the `<manifest>` tags?). did you remember to have your activity `extend Activity`? any other information you can provide?

Comment: I cant post the all code. I extends DroidGap because of phonegap guide.. and I have a question : have I to restart the AVD every time I change my code?

Comment: you have to press "run as application" everytime you change your code. maybe going into the AVD's settings and uninstalling the app might help if that doesnt work.

Comment: Have you followed this guide exactly? Including updating the package name, etc.? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. Other than that, you haven't shown me any code.

Comment: Try a "Project" --> "Clean Project" in eclipse. Then try restarting eclispe and the AVD and running the application.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public class MyFirstAppActivity extends DroidGap { // DroidGap
```

to

```
public class MyFirstAppActivity extends Activity {
```

and create an DroidGap Object from there if needed.